# Is the Debt Collector quest bugged?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I have just started the quest `Debt Collector` and have sweet-talked Jane into paying up. After that, we talked more and she mentioned her caravan in the `Broc Flower Cave`. I also received the objective to collect money from it, despite already being paid by Jane.

Arriving at the cave, the brahmin that should be there is gone and I guess it's because she has already paid. In other words, you can't both make her pay AND loot her caravan. Is this correct?

Comment: I am *shocked* that a FNV quest is possibly bugged.

Comment: Does that mean that bug-questions about FNV never should be posted here again?

Comment: no no, just sarcasm on my part :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Fallout wiki:

"Sometimes Jane's brahmin does not spawn. To fix this with the console type player.placeatme 00116af4 1, this will spawn the brahmin alive, kill it loot it and you're done."

Source: [Debt Collector Bugs](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Debt_Collector#Bugs)